# Create custom column based on condition of how another column value starts with

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, startswith

I have the following dataframe:
[image]
Person Number   Error   Department Name Email
Country
CZ  10054609    The identifier 11380151 is used by Veronika Fi...   CZ:Supply Chain Pohořelice 1 Henkel Cosmeticos...   verca.fialova.2001@gmail.com
CZ  10054620    The identifier 11380126 is used by Radmila Val...   CZ:Supply Chain Pohořelice 1 Henkel VAS (CZM63...   rvalova1@seznam.cz
CZ  10054728    The identifier 11805326 is used by Pavel Pecka...   CZ:Supply Chain Pohořelice 3 Levis (CZM630.415...   pavlias000@seznam.cz
CZ  10054699    The identifier 11380232 is used by Sabina Love...   CZ:Supply Chain Pohořelice 3 Marks and Spencer...   s.loveckova@seznam.cz
CZ  10054727    The identifier 11805358 is used by Tereza Holč...   CZ:Supply Chain Pohořelice 3 Levis (CZM630.415...   tholcapko@seznam.cz

I need to create a column named "Error Type" that follows the condition:

- If the "Error" column starts with "The Identifier" put the value as "Duplicated"
- If the column starts with "The data" put the value as "Transaction"

What would be the best way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

If there is many different values create dictionary for mapping and set values in loop:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Error':['The Identifier 1','The Identifier 3','The data dd','another data']})

#add all possible values
mapping = {'The Identifier': 'Duplicated','The data':'Transaction'}

df['Error'] = df['Error'].str.strip()

for k, v in mapping.items():
   df.loc[df['Error'].str.startswith(k), 'new'] = v
print (df)
              Error          new
0  The Identifier 1   Duplicated
1  The Identifier 3   Duplicated
2       The data dd  Transaction
3      another data          NaN
```

Comment: I am getting "no match" for all of them with the first code

Comment: @PauloCortez - Maybe there are some whitespaces,can you check edited answer?

Comment: isn't it better to create a function with all possible errors and apply this function to the column?